# Undefined method error for a >= symbol.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, symbols

I've built a landing page generator with a referral counter for each person who is referred to the page. When a new subscriber subscribes the are redirected to a referral_page.

After the first subscriber to a page all subsequent subscribers are throwing this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass)
```

I have a list of rewards on the referral page that are in  a rewards/index.html.erb partial. I'm using bootstrap and a simple if statement to turn the reward color green if the refence_count is greater than or equal to the required referral count for that reward.

Here's the rewards/index partial

```
<div class="row">
    <% @rewards.each do |reward| %>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', reward, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-trash", method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

        <% end %>
            <div class="box">

        <% if @subscriber.reference_count >= reward.referral_count_required %>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success btn-fab"><i class="material-icons"><%= reward.referral_count_required %></i></a>
        <% else %>
           <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-warning btn-fab"><i class="material-icons"><%= reward.referral_count_required %></i></a>
        <% end %>

          <h4><%= reward.name %></h4>
          <h4><%= reward.discount %></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
   <% end %>
  </div>
```

What do I need to change to avoid this error?

Comment: it clearly saying that `@subscriber.reference_count` is nil. check in controller `@subscriber` getting its `'reference_count` or not. @user3787971

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you posted; the error message is telling you that when the if condition is evaluated, @subscriber.reference_count is nil, and doesn't have a >= method. It sounds like something isn't getting updated where it should be.

Comment: Yes this is correct. I just went in rails console and set the @subscriber.reference_count to = 0 and it started working.. now need to figure out where that isn't being set properly.